# Running rails server with Gitlab CI Script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automation, continuous-integration, capybara, gitlab-ci

So I have Gitlab CI running, and it's building the project and im attempting to run my capybara/poltergeist integration tests on them, but I realized that when CI runs the rspec command to do these....the server isn't actually running.

So where in my CI.yaml file should I put my "Bundle exec rails s"?

Just right before the rspec command?

For reference this is my CI file.

```
before_script:
  - rbenv install --skip-existing `cat .ruby-version`
  - bundle install
  - RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed

rspec:
  script:
    - bundle exec rspec . --tag type:feature
  tags:
    - ruby
```

Also a side question: When the build finishes and test finishes...how would I shut-down the Rails server that was running. Or would it automatically turn it off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally Capybara starts up its own instance of the app, and shuts it down when finished, you just need to make sure Capybara.server_host is set to an interface it can bind to, and if necessary adjust Capybara.app_host too.

Comment: See thats what I thought, but without doing a "bundle exec rails s" it won't work (Saying it can't find the host) (When i try to visit("/") which I have the app_host set as localhost:3000. Also for reference I do not have "Capybara.run_server = false" set anywhere, and this is being ran as an Rspec test btw. Also running under the poltergeist driver

Comment: server_host which Capybara binds the server to defaults to 127.0.0.1, which (in the world of ipv6) may not be what localhost resolves to.  Try changing Capybara.server_host to localhost, and or changing app_host.  Additionally Capybara.app_host (if set)needs to be a full URI, so http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1  (but try changing server_host and not setting app_host first) Note also that rails starts the dev server on 3000 by default but it's highly unlikely that capybara would start its server on port 3000

Comment: Well I did set app host (to localhost:3000), so your saying set server_host as well? What should I change it to? (maybe im confused what your saying)

Comment: If you're keeping app_host set to 'h t t p://localhost:3000' (it needs to be full url) then you will need to set Capybara.server_host='localhost' and Capybara.server_port=3000

Comment: I will give that a try, thanks!. So your saying if I do that then I won't need to do the "bundle exec rails s" then?

Comment: @msmith1114 Correct -- you do not want to be running the server separately in a normal setup since it prevents Capybara from tracking open requests, etc - which you really want while testing.  The real question is why you need to set any of them, since not setting app_host, server_host, or server_port should just work (unless for some reason Capybara can't bind to 127.0.0.1, or 127.0.0.1 is not accessible in the gitlab ci environment )

Comment: Just out of curiosity...how does Capybara know which app to start up, I guess just based on the directory it's in/

Comment: @msmith1114 It runs whatever is assigned to `Capybara.app` - in a rails process that gets set when you `require 'capybara/rails'`  to a wrapper around `run Rails.application` - which as you surmise is based off the project directory it's in.  https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/2.7_stable/lib/capybara/rails.rb#L4

Comment: Holy crap it worked, I didn't have to run a bundle exec rails server!, So your saying capybara when the tests are done (When ran through rspec) will automatically shut the server down..if so I guess that solved my problem

Comment: @msmith1114 Yes it will shut down the server it starts when exiting

Comment: I am seeing some weird stuff though, methods are not working when rspec is running, (although most of the tests still pass), I know it's the capybara server too since when the tests stop I can no longer access the website, however if I do a "separate bundle exec rails s" the tests failing now work and I no longer get errors about methods not working? They should be using the same TEST database as far as I know? I can't imagine what would be different

Comment: @msmith1114 Without a lot more info on tests that are failing and what they're doing it's impossible to say (and not really the scope of this question) - but by default  bundle exec rails s runs in dev mode, not test so it could be configuration issue in the test environment (or it could be something completely different)

Comment: Well your right, ill look around and maybe ask a diff question if that doesn't work. Thanks! Ill mark this answer as correct as it does fix my original issue.